# how to load the images in my view dynamically in a scroll view in iPhone

Tags: iphone, image, uiscrollview, scroll, dynamic

i want to display many images like thumbnails in a scroll view and and i want the images displayed dynamically we scrolls down or left like a table view cells

can u please tell how to that...

Thanks

with the following code..when we scroll the scroll view im calling this code and able to display the images dynamically (which r only visible) but the problem is.. while scrolling with scroll bars im getting the two images..vertically and horizontally..its only happening when i scroll.. can any body help me out please..?

```
int tileSize;
    int imgSize;
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
        tileSize = 255;
        imgSize = 247;
    }else{
        tileSize = 120;
        imgSize = 116;
    }
    CGRect visibleBounds = [songsContainer bounds];
    for (UIView *tile in [songsContainer subviews]) {
        CGRect scaledTileFrame =[tile frame];
        if (! CGRectIntersectsRect(scaledTileFrame, visibleBounds)) {
            for(UIView *view in [tile subviews])
                [view removeFromSuperview];
            [recycledCells addObject:tile];
            [tile removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
    int maxRow =[songsDict count]-1; // this is the maximum possible row
    int maxCol = noOfRowsInCell-1;  // and the maximum possible column
    int firstNeededRow = MAX(0, floorf(visibleBounds.origin.y / tileSize));
    int firstNeededCol = MAX(0, floorf(visibleBounds.origin.x / tileSize));
    int lastNeededRow  = MIN(maxRow, floorf(CGRectGetMaxY(visibleBounds) / tileSize));
    int lastNeededCol  = MIN(maxCol, floorf(CGRectGetMaxX(visibleBounds) / tileSize));
    NSLog(@".........MaxRow-%d,MaxCol-%d,firstNeddedRow-%d,firstNeededcol-%d,lNR-%d,lNC%d",maxRow, maxCol, firstNeededRow,firstNeededCol,lastNeededRow,lastNeededCol);
    // iterate through needed rows and columns, adding any tiles that are missing
    for (int row = firstNeededRow; row <= lastNeededRow; row++) {
        NSMutableArray *tempArray = (NSMutableArray *)[songsDict objectAtIndex:row];
        for (int col = firstNeededCol; col <= lastNeededCol ; col++) {
            BOOL tileIsMissing = (firstVisibleRow > row || firstVisibleColumn > col || 
                                  lastVisibleRow  < row || lastVisibleColumn  < col);
            if (tileIsMissing) {
                UIView *tile = (UIView *)[self dequeueReusableTile];

                if (!tile) {
                    // the scroll view will handle setting the tile's frame, so we don't have to worry about it
                    tile = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease]; 
                    tile.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                }
                //tile.image = image for row and col;
                // set the tile's frame so we insert it at the correct position
                CGRect frame = CGRectMake(tileSize * col, tileSize * row, imgSize, imgSize);
                tile.frame = frame;
                if(col<[tempArray count])
                    [self addContentForTile:tile:row:col];
                else tile.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                [songsContainer addSubview:tile];

            }
        }
    }
    firstVisibleRow = firstNeededRow+1; firstVisibleColumn = firstNeededCol+1;
    lastVisibleRow  = lastNeededRow;  lastVisibleColumn  = lastNeededCol;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is create your scrollview however you want. You have to decide whether you want a grid layout, or linear layout. In addition, if grid, do you want it locked to the horizontal bounds, locked to vertical, so it scrolls either vertical or horizontal, respectively.

Once you have that sorted out, then what I recommend is taking the architecture similar to how a tableview functions. That is, create individual "cells" that will hold your thumbnails. Once you have these cells, you add them as subviews of your scrollview, at certain offsets (you need to do some math on the x/y planes).

Comment: but the app Amazon's WindowShop ipad app can be scrollable vertically and horizontally... they are loading dynamically right?

Comment: You don't have to lock either of the axis, just usually, in thumbnail views, one either locks horizontal or vertical axis in the scrollview. What I said still applies if you don't want to lock either axis.

Comment: The things you place on the scrollview are going to be individual cells. These cells can be UIImageView subclasses or whatever you like. Give them an identifier for reuse, then in your scrollview subclass, you will need to do the math to line up the cells how you want. You will also want to keep two `NSSet`s around, one for recycled cells and one for the visible cells. When you dequeue a cell, check the recycled cells, if anyObject isn't nil, pass that to the user, so you avoid having to allocate a new one. Otherwise, return nil. Line up the cells in the scrollview however you like.

Comment: The trick is in calculating visible cells. You will want to preload some cells that are off screen so your user sees cells with content when they scroll down quickly. When a cell is visible, add it to the visible cells `NSSet`, and when it is not visible, you remove it from the visible cells set, and add it to the recycled cells set. This is the crux of cell reuse. I'll leave the rest as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Hi jer, i tried as u said but having one problem..edited the question. please tell me wts the problem.. is with the code..?

Answer (score 0):

Start with a scroll view and add each image in an UIImageView as a subview to the scrollview at a certain location.

One thing to have in mind is to only hold in memory the images that are currently shown and their immediate neighbours.

Comment: Depending on how many image views he has that could consume a lot of memory. He's going to want to look (for robustness) at a cell & queueing mechanism